# Multiple AnimationController in ListView.builder Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I’m trying to send the controller value (from the parent page) to animate the animations on the child page.

the result that I expected is only one animation that’s been clicked being animated, but what I got is all of the animations being animated at the same time.

How can I differentiate the controller based on the index of the data that’s been clicked?

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you've currently done.

Comment: Please edit your question with code and the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I got around by disposing the animationController when I didn't need it.

```
AnimationController? animationController;
```

```
void startAnimation() async {
    animationController = AnimationController(...)
    await animationController!.forward();
    stopAnimation();
  }
```

```
void stopAnimation() {
    animationController?.dispose();
    animationController = null;
}
```

It's janky as heck, and I dont know why flutter functions like this, but this worked for me.